# How to implement a console application to read xml files from FTP storage in Azure?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-webjobs

I would like to create some console application. In this console application I would like to read scheduled all xml files from some location (a location in Azure with FTP access), and for each readed xml file I would like to create a new list item in a Office 365 site. I am thinking about to implement the console application as a Azure webjob. Is there some possibility in Azure to add files to some location by FTP? This location needs to be also accessable from the Azure web job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are looking to FTP an Azure instance you can achieve it by following the below article https://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/ and use .Net FTP client to move files to FTP location.

AzCopy utility is also a widely used tool for this kind of operations.

It is recommended to use Azure blob to store such XML  files using REST end point which provides greater throughput and better security.

It is better to use Azure functions instead of a Azure Web job for multiple reasons like web job hosted on app service shares the resource which you is actually required for your web app or other app to run and it is also a part of app service plan. Moreover web jobs is kind of obsolete as the Microsoft Azure itself promotes Azure Functions instead of Web Jobs. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs
and decide accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some possibility in Azure to add files to some location by FTP? This location needs to be also accessable from the Azure web job.

Firstly, as we know, App Service enables us to [access site’s files via FTP](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp), and we could run console application as WebJobs in Azure App Service web app, we could also access files from site `D:\home` in the WebJobs functions, like this.

```
string targetDirectory = @"D:\home\myxml";

List<string> fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".xml").ToList();

foreach (var item in fileEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But App Service has [limited storage space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits), we should not store too much static files on web site server. As Mohammed Shamil said, if it is possible, you could try to store your XML files in Azure storage. And some storage tools (such as AzCopy, Azure Storage Explorer etc) could be used to upload/download files easily.